# Cohen–Sutherland algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I was reading [Cohen–Sutherland algorithm on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm)  and I am confused in these two parts,

```
int ComputeOutCode(double x, double y) {
    ...
    if (x < xmin)       code |= LEFT;
    else if (x > xmax)  code |= RIGHT;
    if (y < ymin)       code |= BOTTOM;
    else if (y > ymax)  code |= TOP;
    ...
}
```

and

```
if (outcodeOut & TOP) {           // point is above the clip rectangle
    x = x0 + (x1 - x0) * (ymax - y0) / (y1 - y0);
    y = ymax;
} else if (outcodeOut & BOTTOM) { // point is below the clip rectangle
    x = x0 + (x1 - x0) * (ymin - y0) / (y1 - y0);
    y = ymin;
} else if (outcodeOut & RIGHT) {  // point is to the right of clip rectangle
    y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (xmax - x0) / (x1 - x0);
    x = xmax;
} else if (outcodeOut & LEFT) {   // point is to the left of clip rectangle
    y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (xmin - x0) / (x1 - x0);
    x = xmin;
}
```

What I am confused is, How does it handle points who are top-left, top right, etc. It just handles top, left, right and bottom.

Why use `|` in `code |= LEFT;` and `outcodeOut & TOP` in `if-else` below it? I know that these two somehow handle all 8 possible cases but I don't know how.

Comment: So, slipping into coaching mode: what do you understand |= does?

Answer (score 3):

`code` is a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) which uses bitwise boolean operators to store whether certain flags are set or not.

`code |= LEFT;` is short for `code = code | LEFT;` and sets the `LEFT` flag. `outcodeOut & LEFT` is an expression that is only true (!=0) when the `LEFT` flag is set.

The shown excerpt does indeed not handle all (16) possible cases at once, but it's part of a larger loop that may run multiple times. So it's done in several iterations.

Comment: Now I am confused how line `(200,200)->(900,850)` is clipped for clip rectangle `(100,100) (800,800)`. If we use `outcodeOut&RIGHT` block, it'll get solved. But the algorithm will use `TOP` block then `RIGHT` block, but its still solved somehow.